# Unexpected error while processing hprof file: null

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having a massive memory issue on specific devices where a ton of memory is allocated out of nowhere. I'm trying to do a heapdump to figure out what is allocating the memory, but when I attempt to open the heapdump file, I get an error in Android Studio:

`HprofView - Unexpected error while processing hprof file: null`

[image: Error occurring]

I've done some web searching, but there aren't any references to this error as far as I can tell. I just need help getting the heap dump, I can fix my app from there.

**Edit:** I tried converting the dump file, but it gave me another error:

`Convert Android Java Heap Dump - Unexpected error while converting heap dump: ERROR: read 16710959 of 33177623 bytes`

[image: error when trying to export to standard hprof]

Comment: Same do I on Nexus 6 with Android 5.0, with only one launched application consuming near 170Mb

I have downgraded my Nexus 6 to Android 5.0 and have not remembered to have such troubles on Android 6.0 - but may be I am wrong

Comment: Dealing with the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @ryye unfortunately, no, I didn't resolve this issue. I ended up fixing the underlying memory issue in my app, so I haven't had to deal with this problem since them. I was kind of hoping someone from the AS dev team would see this and do something about it. Unfortunately, it didn't get any attention.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a definitive answer, but in my experience it seems to happen when the app is close to its memory usage limit. This is obviously not ideal when you're trying to debug an `OutOfMemoryError`!

2 things I can suggest to get around the problem:

1. Try using a different device/emulator. e.g. I've found this issue is quite common on my Samsung S5, but happens less often on my Nexus 4.
2. Pause the application some time *before* it runs out of memory, then get the heap dump at that point. This isn't ideal, but memory leaks tend to cause a problem over time, rather all at once, so you should still be able to diagnose the leak.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help with the problem. I am able to get the heap dump, but Android Studio cannot display them, per the error messages I supplied.

Comment: Also, the issue that I was having with the allocation was not a memory leak as far as I can discern. **It only happened on specific devices** and was a 400MB allocation in less than a second. It was very specifically 400MB and never more or less. The allocation appeared to happen between activity calls, after `startActivity()` and before `onCreate()`.

Comment: You're getting a file with the .hprof suffix, but I don't think it's a valid heap dump. I think it's running out of memory *whilst capturing the heap dump*. I've never heard of the issue you describe, but you have my sympathies!